# Issues with tinyMCE and 'mceAddEditor'

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

So I have a page that uses JavaScript to dynamicaly add `<textarea>`s. I need these text areas to use tinyMCE. I am using tinyMCE v4.

I have an init function for tinyMCE

```
function TinyMceEditConfig() {
        tinymce.init({
      selector: '.editor'
    });
}
```

then i call the function

```
TinyMceEditConfig();
```

then i create dynamic text areas. Basically, someone selects they want to enter text from a drop down list. once they select it the text area is generated. when a user clicks the dropdown it calls a function that contains this code (my brackets may be messed up here...dont pay attention to that, lol, they are fine in my code, just look at the meat)

```
return $('<div>', {
        'css': {'display': 'none'},
        'html': [
            $('<textarea>', {
                'value': this.text_value,
                'placeholder': this.placeholder_text,
                'class': "editor"] });

};
```

so at this point, i can click the dropdown to generate the text area (plain text). if i refresh the page tinyMCE kicks in and everything is fine. looking around online the following code is supposed to fix my problem so that tinyMCE will show as soon as the field is added. this is in my code immidiatly after i call the last code snipit.

```
tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceAddEditor', false, ".editor");
```

however, it does not.....any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `init()` on a textarea until it exists on the page.  If I understand your comments above you are first invoking your TinyMCE `init()` function and then later adding textarea elements to the page.  This won't work as the `init()` will only handle things that already exist on the page.

When you dynamically add the new textarea to the page you then need to call `tinymce.init()` after the textarea is part of the DOM in order to have TinyMCE appear in place of the textarea.

It might help to create a TinyMCE Fiddle (or CodePen etc) to show what you are actually doing as that might help people see where things are failing.